# Best ways of performing server side validations on data using Java

Tags: java, validation, server-side

Could someone guide me on this fundamental question: What are the best way ways of performing server side validations on data using Java?

I would like to know if there are open source libraries available to perform server side validations as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: that depends on what you whant to valitate. Do you whant to valitate if the data format is coorrect, the sender is valid or what do you whant?

Comment: It is better to use **DWR** for any server side validations for any framework.
***write once reuse any where*** concept can be implemented in validations using **DWR**.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on which  web developement framework you are using.

---

**Raw JSP Servlet**

If you are using simple jsp servlet, Then I would suggest add one validator package/jar for each form/jsp screen. and validate it from controller before passing to service.

---

**JSF**

If you are using JSF then there is very well designed validation phase provided , You can use ready made validators (you can just add annotation on the form field and its done) or you can create your own validators also.

---

**Spring MVC**

If you are using  Spring MVC , it has also got a [saperate layer for validation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/validation.html).

---

**Struts**

Struts has also got [saperate layer for validation](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.4/userGuide/dev_validator.html)

Comment: I am using Raw JSP. I think I will use the first recomendation. Thank you for your reply

Comment: @Jigar: Are there other alternatives to one validator? I store all my (survey) form attributes like question1 question2 etc. in a collection object. I use this same collection object to generate an XML as well. Hence is would be good if I could use something that accepted collection objects rather than Beans.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking to validate POJOs, you can have a look at the Oval framework http://oval.sourceforge.net/

JSR-303 (and its implementations) may also help if ur app is designed based on pojos or beans

Here is a sample custom validation in OVal:
Lets say you have to validate variables map in SomeValueClass and ensure the value of key 'greeting' is always present.

```
public class SomeValueClass {

@FormCollection
Map variables;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SomeValueClass svc1 = new SomeValueClass();
    svc1.variables = new HashMap();
    svc1.variables.put("greeting", "");

    Validator validator = new Validator();
    List<ConstraintViolation> violations = validator.validate(svc1);
    System.out.println("svc1 violations.size() = " + violations.size());
}
```

The @FormCollection annotation on "Map variables;" is a custom validator and is as below:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.METHOD})
@net.sf.oval.configuration.annotation.Constraint(checkWith = FormCollectionCheck.class)
public @interface FormCollection {
  String message() default "Some errors in the form";
}
```

And the constraint check class will look like this:

```
public class FormCollectionCheck extends AbstractAnnotationCheck<FormCollection> {
  public boolean isSatisfied(Object validatedObject, Object valueToValidate, OValContext context, Validator validator) {
    Map vars = (Map) valueToValidate;
    return !(vars.get("greeting")==null || ((String)vars.get("greeting")).length()<=0);
  }
}
```

Hope that helps,
Cheers

Comment: @aldrin : Does this mean that I can validate a collection object? For instrance I am storing the attributes of a web form in a collection object. Key would be the question asked and value would be the response of the user. I am using this collection object so that I can generate an XML. It would be great if this framework could validate the values in the collection object. I did have a look at you link but was not convinced. Could you show me some examples?

Comment: @Khushroo You will need to use a custom validator. I've updated my answer with an example that may help you.

Comment: @aldrin: thank you for your prompt help mate. I appreciate it. Unfortunatly I am not a member so I cannot increment the counter. again thank you.

Comment: @aldrin: quick question aldrin: In the isSatisfied(), at the moment you are doing a check for only one value in the Map hence this method looks very neat. However if your have a like ten values to check you will need to use if...else conditions quite extensively which I am not a big fan of. Any work arounds for that? Thanks again.

Comment: @Khushroo If you have to check all the values in the map, then you have to iterate through it. not much choice there. if it is the same check for all the items, then you can use a loop.

Comment: @aldrin: Yeah I have different checks for each questin some may also be the same but yeah cant really make do without if..else conditions. Anyways thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

then you go for the framework which are providing inbuilt validations like struts etc. Those will provide you validation component. Also its an opensource.